# how do i put drawline in inside the JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Am creating medical waveform in inside the `JFrame`. but i want to put that waveform inside the `jpanel` for multithreading concept. i don't know how to do that can anyone please advise me.

Here is my code it will create wave form in jframe. how can i put that waveform inside the jpanel jp2.

> Server code

```
public class samplehex extends JFrame {
JPanel jp2;
samplehex() {
    jp2 = new JPanel();
}
private static final int BSIZE = 1024;
int flag,spo2_wave,ecg1_wave,ecg2_wave,xpos_ecg1=20,xpos_ecg2=20,xpos_spo2=20;
IntBuffer ecg = IntBuffer.allocate(1024);
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(BSIZE);
Label l;    
Font fpi = new Font("",Font.BOLD,10);
int x=0, p, q, r, y, px, pp, pq, pr, py = 0,s,buff_reset=0; 
public class samplehexa implements Runnable {
    Graphics g2d = (getGraphics());
    public void run()
    {   
        int port = 4444;        
        try
        {                               
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);           
            System.out.println("server's IP adress: "+InetAddress.getLocalHost()+"\nPort Number: "+server.getLocalPort());
            System.out.println("waiting for connection...");
            while(true)
            {
                Socket connect=server.accept();             
                System.err.println("Connected...");
                System.out.println("Connected to ..." + connect.getInetAddress() +" with port number: "+connect.getPort());     
                ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
                short[] ECG=new short[100];
                while(connect.isConnected())
                {   
                    int red = -1;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[64*1024];
                    while ((red = connect.getInputStream().read(buffer)) > -1) 
                    {                           
                        StringBuilder data1 = new StringBuilder();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, red); 
                        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();                      
                        StringBuilder newdata = new StringBuilder();
                        for (byte b : bytes) {
                            newdata=data1.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
                        }
                        String content=newdata.toString();
                        int count=0;
                        String[] array=content.split(" ");
                        for(int m=0;m<array.length;m++) {
                            String inside_loop=array[m];
                            lst.add(inside_loop);
                        }
                        while (lst.contains("02") && lst.contains("03")) {
                            if(!(lst.get(0).contains("02"))) { 
                                int value = lst.indexOf("02");  
                                lst.subList(0, value).clear();
                            } else {
                                int start =lst.indexOf("02");
                                int end =lst.indexOf("03");
                                if(start<end) {
                                    ArrayList<String> sub_list = new ArrayList<String>();
                                    for(int k=start;k<=end;k++) {
                                        String hex=lst.get(k);
                                        sub_list.add(hex);
                                    }
                                    String[] newres = new String[sub_list.size()];
                                    for(int h=0;h<sub_list.size();h++) {
                                        newres[h]=sub_list.get(h);
                                    }
                                    lst.subList(start, end+1).clear();                                  
                                    int convert=Integer.parseInt(newres[1],16);
                                    int check=convert-1;
                                    int i=0;
                                    if(check==newres.length-1) {
                                        try {
                                            Thread.sleep(4);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        if(newres[0].contains("02") && newres[check].contains("03")) {
                                            i=i+3;
                                            if(newres[i].contains("21")){   
                                                i++;                                            
                                                int[] Spo2_wave=new int[newres.length];
                                                Spo2_wave[i]=Integer.parseInt(newres[i],16);
                                                spo2_wave=Spo2_wave[i];
                                                r=spo2_wave;            
                                                //-->SPO2 WaveForm Design Check This
                                                for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
                                                    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                                                    g2d.drawLine(xpos_spo2+k,431,xpos_spo2+k,555);
                                                }
                                                g2d.setColor(Color.white);
                                                g2d.drawLine(xpos_spo2,555-pr,xpos_spo2+1,555-r);
                                                pr=r;
                                                xpos_spo2=xpos_spo2+2;
                                                if(xpos_spo2==828){
                                                    xpos_spo2=16;   
                                                }   
                                                //--<SPO2 WaveForm Design Check This
                                                i++;
                                                int[] Bar_graph=new int[newres.length];
                                                Bar_graph[i]=Integer.parseInt(newres[i],16);
                                                i++;
                                            }                                         
                                        }                                       
                                    }   
                                }                       
                            }                                
                        }                      
                    }   
                }               
            }                       
        }               
        catch (IOException e)   
        {
            System.err.println("Error in connection");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }   
}
```

> > designing code

```
public class sample extends samplehex {

public static List<int[]> map = new ArrayList<int[]>();
static Button Connect;
int temp=0,move=0,xpos=20,j=0;  
Stroke str = new BasicStroke();

public sample() {
    super();
    l = new Label("ECG Lead1");
    l.setBackground(Color.black);
    l.setForeground(Color.green);
    l.setFont(fpi);
    l.setBounds(0,0,60,8);
    setSize(1025, 730);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jp2.setSize(830,250);
    jp2.setLocation(5,335);
    jp2.setLayout(null);
    jp2.setBackground(Color.black);        
    jp2.setVisible(true);
    jp2.getGraphics();               
    add(jp2);
    Connect = new Button("Connect");
    Connect.setBounds(850,660,80,30);
    Connect.setVisible(true);                                                                               
    Connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            new Thread(new samplehexa()).start();
            //drawLines(getGraphics());
            //screen1.getGraphics();
        }
    });
    add(Connect);
}    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    sample s = new sample();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class which extends from `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method and render your output there

Take an instance of this panel and add it to what ever container you like, for example a `JFrame`, a `JInternalFrame`, another panel, what ever

Remember, Swing is single threaded and not thread safe.  All updates to the UI MUST be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: Please suggest some reference code. or how to add  Graphics g2d=getGraphics(); inside internalframe(screen1).

Comment: You don't, as I said, you override the `paintComponent` of a custom class which extends from something like `JPanel`, you then add this to what ever container you want. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how paint works

Comment: i can't use extends concept in my code is there any other way to do this please advise.

Comment: The question is, why not?  The ability to extend objects in the corner stone of OO and Java.  Custom painting will only through extension, it's (the better) way to perform custom painting.  How did you create it in your `JFrame` if not through extension

Comment: screen1.add(jp2, g2d); why it's not working? but it won't display any error. give some sample code for me please.

Comment: add(Component, Object) provides you a means to add a component to a Container with a layout constraint. Some layout managers ignore the constraint, others will throw an Exception if it's not the correct type. This is not how painting is done

Comment: Thanks for your valuable commands...

Comment: i use code for get a panel graphics(Graphics g2d = jpanel.getgraphics();) it will works.

Comment: That is NOT how custom paint works, see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details